# PHP Notice: Undefined index: selecting-message

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I get always this error:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: selecting-message in /content-protection.php on line 390" and I have tried for many hours to solve this.
```

I hope someone can help me.

Line 390 Code:

```
$message = $_POST['selecting-message'];
$update  = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$table` SET enabled='$enabled', alert='$alert', message='$message' WHERE id=14");

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=content-protection">';
}
```

Comment: Post the code for the previous page that is generating the POST data.  What that notice is telling you is that `selecting-message` is not set in the POST array.  Undefined index means it isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notice is telling you that the POST array does not contain an element with the key `selecting-message`.  That could be an empty field on your form from the previous page, a typo or any number of other reasons WHY it doesn't exist.

Simply check for a value instead of assuming it is there:

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['selecting-message'] ) ) {
    $message = $_POST['selecting-message'];
    $update  = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$table` SET enabled='$enabled', alert='$alert', message='$message' WHERE id=14");

    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=content-protection">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe read something on SQL injections. Passing an POST value directly into a query without sanitizing will end in a hacked website.

Answer (score 0):

I find the 'unexpected end of file' error is usually caused by an unbalanced brace '{}'somewhere in the code. Check through it and see if there's a '{' somewhere without a corresponding '}'

kev.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple PHP web shell, as mentioned above allowing code execution on your web server. Better get rid of it and harden your application